# Asynchronous Searching & Reordering

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, asynchronous, laravel-4

I'm after some advice in what direction to take the develop of a new feature in ongoing project. I've been asked to build a new search to act like the hotel search results on hipmunk or kayak - where I load the data in small blocks, say for example 10 hotels per call and reorder as the data comes in.

The site is written in Laravel 4 and the old search was using a basic search with pagination through infinite scroll. Someone mentioned that it would be easier to build this feature in a javascript framework like AngularJS, although this site is already built but I would consider rewriting if there was the benefit.

Currently the project is set up with a backend team who provide us with an API for the data, originally we had considered AngularJS but the data generally requires editing to be useful. The other option may be to use the current Laravel site and turn it into a middle API ready for a javascript framework.

I'm not really sure what direction to take on this. Write my own custom jquery plugin to handle it and keep the current site, or go for AngularJS. I'd really appreciate any advice

I have found a useful plugin that may help me a lot: http://mixitup.io/

Below is an example of the hipmunk search, you can see they have different hotels. I took these screenshots right after each other. I'm trying to recreate a search system like this.

[image]

**[Update]**

After doing further research into different options I found using an Observable Array to keep track of everything was a good idea. I found small library to be used with underscore.js:

https://github.com/mennovanslooten/Observable-Arrays

Now its just a case of handling the updating and filtering of the array which I've got a large amount written so far.

Comment: Sorry, could be my english, but your question isn't very clear about what are you asking. Could you be more clear about it? If it's possible, call me back and I see if I can help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes some frameworks would have helped to create this kind of functionality but since your are not necessarily familiar with those framework it is simpler/faster for you to code it yourself.

Here some advice of how you could implement it:

## Backend

In *Laravel* create your API routes in `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('api/hotels/{ordering}/page/{page}', 'ApiController@order');
//todo Validate data with regular expression
```

Create your controller `app/controllers/ApiController.php`:

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

    public function getOrder($ordering, $page){

       $query = Hotel::select('*');

        switch($ordering){
            case "price":

                $query->orderBy('price', 'ASC');

            break;
            case "review":
                //...
            break; 
            default:
                //...
            break;
        }

        $query->take(10);

        //...paging

        $hotels = $query->get();

        return Response::json($hotels);
    }
}
```

## Frontend

In your HTML create your buttons with different ordering actions:

```
Filter by:
<div class="btn" data-action="price">Price</button>
<div class="btn" data-action="review">Reviews</button>

Hotels:
<ul id="hotels"></ul>
```

In Javascript when a button is clicked you fetch the data calling the Laravel API:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {

    var ordering = $(this).data('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "api/hotels/"+ordering+"/page/"+currentPage,            
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){         

            var $list = $('#hotels');

            $.each(result.hotels, function(idx, hotel) {

                $list.append('Hotel: '+hotel.name);
                //...
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, exceptionobj) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jQuery + jQuery UI feature called "Autocomplete" with ajax datasource?

Here's an example...

**html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-loading {
            background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                function log( message ) {
                    $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
                    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
                }
                $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
                    source: "search.php",
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
            <input id="birds" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: Arial;">
            Result:
            <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As for the data source (search.php for e.g.): http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Full demo / documentation / samples : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion I'm taking about the how the search results are loaded in. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Just a note: Even if this was what the was OP looking for, i would recommend using AngularUI's typeahead feature instead of going back to DOM manipulation with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. But it appears that you are currently delivering full HTML content to the client and you might want to change that to only transmit real data which is then rendered into HTML on the client. You could do that with jQuery and plugins, but it would be rather simple to do this in AngularJS.

Basically you need some simple code to output the data returned by the server. In the simplest for just a repeat iterating. Such a repeat can also be filtered/ordered. So something like this:

```
<div ng:repeat="hotel in hotels">
  <h1>{{hotel.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{hotel.description}}</p>
  ...whatever...
</div>
```

Then you just need to get hotels filled with the data which can be easily achieved with AngularJS $http feature and having something on your server providing data/search results in JSON format. This you would also need if you use jQuery with the plugin you mentioned. Oh and the other features of that plugin like CSS transitions when the displayed data changes is built-in in AngularJS as well and can be easily utilized.

So if you want to go the way of delivering data to the client and then using JavaScript to render the output, you would need to have some server API which can provide the data in JSON. You would need this no matter which further route you choose (jQuery/MixItUp or AngularJS).

This is about all advise I can give you with the input you provided.